# Runtime error during LESS translation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, less

Everything is fine on my local server. However, after I publish to my hosting environment the following error occurs, even after I delete everything from style.less file:

[image: Error Image]

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Engine name: MSIE JavaScript engine
Engine version: Classic
Error code: -2146827850
Category: Microsoft JScript runtime error
Line number: 9
Column number: 17006
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
  web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error
  and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.AssetTranslationException:
  During translation of LESS-code, readed from the file /Content/custom/style.less,
  to CSS-code syntax error has occurred.
Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current
  web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be
  identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace:
  AssetTranslationException: During translation of LESS-code, readed from the file '/Content/custom/style.less', to CSS-code syntax error has occurred. See more details:
    BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator.InnerTranslate(IAsset asset, LessCompiler lessCompiler, Boolean enableNativeMinification) +270
    BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator.Translate(IAsset asset) +166
    BundleTransformer.Core.HttpHandlers.AssetHandlerBase.InnerTranslateAsset(String translatorName, IAsset asset, ITransformer transformer, Boolean isDebugMode) +97
    BundleTransformer.Less.HttpHandlers.LessAssetHandler.TranslateAsset(IAsset asset, ITransformer transformer, Boolean isDebugMode) +28
    BundleTransformer.Core.HttpHandlers.AssetHandlerBase.ProcessAsset(String assetVirtualPath, String bundleVirtualPath) +195
    BundleTransformer.Core.HttpHandlers.AssetHandlerBase.GetProcessedAssetContent(String assetVirtualPath, String bundleVirtualPath) +206
    BundleTransformer.Core.HttpHandlers.AssetHandlerBase.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase context) +227
  HttpException (0x80004005): During translation of LESS-code, readed from the file '/Content/custom/style.less', to CSS-code syntax error has occurred. See more details:
    BundleTransformer.Core.HttpHandlers.AssetHandlerBase.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase context) +288
    BundleTransformer.Core.HttpHandlers.AssetHandlerBase.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +40
    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Comment: Welcome. Please paste this text into the question rather than using a link to an image. Links will eventually expire and make the question useless to others. Including the text also allows folks to use snippets of code/output in their answers if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows Server 2008R2 Service Pack1 with **IE8** installed. After I updated IE to the latest version the issue disappeared.